Не могу сделать так чтоб появился блок 'sub-submenu-expandable' при нажатие на 'has-sub-submenu'


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.has-submenu').click(function () {
        if ($('.has-submenu').hasClass('mobil_active')) {
            /*Удаление классов вперед назад и удаление блоков*/
            $(this).removeClass('mobil_active').siblings().removeClass('to-left');
            $('.has-submenu').not(this).removeClass( "to-left");
            $('.header-submenu').css('display', 'none');
            /*------------------------------------------*/
        } else {
            /*Добавление классов вперед назад и блоков*/
            $(this).addClass('mobil_active').siblings().removeClass('to-left');
            $('.has-submenu').not(this).addClass("to-left");
            $('.header-submenu').css('display', 'block');
            $('.sub-submenu-expandable').addClass('to-right');
            /*------------------------------------------*/
        }
    })
});
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, * :after, * :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
@media (max-width: 620px) {
    .has-submenu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .links {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .header-bottom-links-row > li.has-submenu > .ttl::after {
        content: "";
        width: 10px;
        height: 17px;
        background: url(mob-menu-arrow.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        margin-top: -16px;
    }
    .ttl {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .ttl > a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .submenu-list {
        list-style-type: none;
    }


    .mobil_active{

    }

     li.mobil_active > .ttl:after {
        background-image: url(mob-menu-back.svg) !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        right: auto !important;
    }
    ul.submenu-list > li.has-sub-submenu > .ttl:after {
        content: "";
        width: 10px;
        height: 17px;
        background: url(mob-menu-arrow.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .to-left {
        display: none;
    }

    .header-submenu {
        display: none;
    }
    .to-right {
        display: none;
    }
    
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header-bottom-links-row">
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">О Мгике</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Приветствие ректора</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">История МГИКа</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Структура МГИКа</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Ученый совет</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-sub-submenu">
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <div class="submenu-arrow"></div>
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Сведенья об образовательной организации</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sub-submenu-expandable">
                                <ul class="sub-submenu">
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Основные сведения
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Структура и органы управления образовательной организацией
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Документы
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Образование
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Образовательные стандарты и требования
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Руководство
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Педагогический состав
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Материально-техническое обеспечение и оснащенность
                                            образовательного процесса. Доступная среда
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Стипендии и меры поддержки обучающихся
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Платные образовательные услуги
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Финансово-хозяйственная деятельность
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Вакантные места для приема (перевода) обучающихся
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Международное сотрудничество
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            Организация питания в образовательной организации
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Оплата</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">ПАО БАНК "ФК Открытие"</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Наука</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrows"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Государственная научная аттестация: присуждение ученых
                                    степеней</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Подразделение и сотрудники</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Журналы</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Научно-творческий студенческий Альманах "Гамаюн"</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Научные мероприятия</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Результаты исследований</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Новости и Информация</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Информационные ресурсы</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Конгресс "Вузы культуры и искусств в международном
                                    гуманитарном сотрудничестве "</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Архив конгрессов</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Национальный проект "Наука и университеты"</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Локальные нормативные акты в области науки</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Контакты</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Образование</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Факультеты</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Кафедры</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Магистратура</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Аспирантура</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Ассисентура-стажировка</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Центр непрерывного образования и повышения
                                    квалификации</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Международный отдел</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Студентам</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Расписание</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Новости и обьявления</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Анонсы</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Студенческий совет</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Общежитие</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Центр непрерывного образования и повышения
                                    квалификации</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Международный отдел</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Федеральные проекты</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Федеральный проект "Творческие люди"</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Федеральный проект "Придумано в России"</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Издательский центр</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Каталог книг</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Новости</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Команда издательства</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Пресс-служба</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Новости</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Анонсы</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Для СМИ</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Фотогалерея</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Научный журнал</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Весник</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Культура и образование: научно -информационный</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Журнал вузов культуры и искусств</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Контакты</a>
            <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-submenu">
            <div class="header-submenu-cont">
                <div class="header-submenu-1">
                    <ul class="submenu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Приёмная комиссия</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Факультеты</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Подразделения</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ttl">
                                <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Адрес</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>




https://codepen.io/levacheb/pen/ByBBZaZ

За основу взял ответ Льва из комментария к задаче.
Чуть оптимизировал: убрал повторения и упростил код.
UPD
Я добавил уникальные идентификаторы через атрибут data-menu-id в HTML, чтобы упростить управление каждым пунктом меню. Также разделил элементы стрелок (.dropdown_arrow, .submenu-arrow) и ссылки для более точного контроля, а вложенные меню обернул в отдельные контейнеры (.header-submenu, .sub-submenu-expandable) для ясности структуры.
В jQuery упростил логику, добавив чёткое управление состояниями через классы (mobil_active) и анимации (slideDown / slideUp). События клика теперь обрабатываются отдельно для основного меню и вложенных уровней. Также добавил обработку кликов вне меню, чтобы автоматически закрывать открытые пункты, и убрал лишнее наложение событий, используя stopPropagation.


$(document).ready(function() {
  // Клик по стрелке основного подменю
  $('.dropdown_arrow').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Останавливаем всплытие, чтобы избежать лишних обработчиков

    const $parent = $(this).closest('.has-submenu'); // Родительский элемент
    const $submenu = $parent.find('.header-submenu'); // Его подменю

    if ($parent.hasClass('mobil_active')) {
      // Если меню активно, скрываем его
      $parent.removeClass('mobil_active');
      $submenu.slideUp(); // Анимация скрытия
    } else {
      // Скрываем все активные пункты
      $('.has-submenu').removeClass('mobil_active');
      $('.header-submenu').slideUp();

      // Активируем текущий пункт меню
      $parent.addClass('mobil_active');
      $submenu.slideDown(); // Анимация показа
    }
  });

  // Клик по стрелке вложенного подменю
  $('.submenu-arrow').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Останавливаем всплытие, чтобы не затронуть другие обработчики

    const $parent = $(this).closest('.has-sub-submenu'); // Родительский элемент
    const $subExpandable = $parent.find('.sub-submenu-expandable'); // Вложенное меню

    if ($subExpandable.is(':visible')) {
      // Если вложенное меню видно, скрываем его
      $subExpandable.slideUp(); // Анимация скрытия
      $parent.removeClass('mobil_active'); // Убираем активный класс
    } else {
      // Скрываем все вложенные меню
      $('.sub-submenu-expandable').slideUp();
      $('.has-sub-submenu').removeClass('mobil_active');

      // Показываем текущее вложенное меню
      $subExpandable.slideDown(); // Анимация показа
      $parent.addClass('mobil_active'); // Добавляем активный класс
    }
  });

  // Закрытие меню при клике вне его
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.has-submenu').removeClass('mobil_active'); // Сбрасываем активное состояние
    $('.header-submenu, .sub-submenu-expandable').slideUp(); // Скрываем все меню
  });

  // Остановка всплытия при клике внутри меню
  $('.header-submenu, .sub-submenu-expandable').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
* :after,
* :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  width: 621px;
}

@media (min-width: 620px) {
  .has-submenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .links {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .header-bottom-links-row>li.has-submenu>.ttl::after {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 17px;
    background: url(mob-menu-arrow.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    margin-top: -16px;
  }
  .ttl {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .ttl>a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .submenu-list {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .mobil_active {}
  li.mobil_active>.ttl:after {
    background-image: url(mob-menu-back.svg) !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: auto !important;
  }
  ul.submenu-list>li.has-sub-submenu>.ttl:after {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 17px;
    background: url(mob-menu-arrow.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .to-left {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-submenu {
    display: none;
  }
  .to-right {
    display: none;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header-bottom-links-row">
  <!-- Пункт меню 1 -->
  <li class="has-submenu" data-menu-id="menu1">
    <div class="ttl">
      <a href="#" class="border_bottom">О Мгике</a>
      <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-submenu">
      <ul class="submenu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Приветствие ректора</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">История МГИКа</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Структура МГИКа</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ученый совет</a></li>
        <!-- Подпункт с вложенным меню -->
        <li class="has-sub-submenu">
          <div class="ttl">
            <a href="#">Сведения об организации</a>
            <div class="submenu-arrow"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="sub-submenu-expandable">
            <ul class="sub-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Основные сведения</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Образование</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <!-- Пункт меню 2 -->
  <li class="has-submenu" data-menu-id="menu2">
    <div class="ttl">
      <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Оплата</a>
      <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-submenu">
      <ul class="submenu-list">
        <li><a href="#">ПАО БАНК "ФК Открытие"</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <!-- Пункт меню 3 -->
  <li class="has-submenu" data-menu-id="menu3">
    <div class="ttl">
      <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Наука</a>
      <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-submenu">
      <ul class="submenu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Государственная научная аттестация</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Журналы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Научные мероприятия</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <!-- Пункт меню 4 -->
  <li class="has-submenu" data-menu-id="menu4">
    <div class="ttl">
      <a href="#" class="border_bottom">Образование</a>
      <div class="dropdown_arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-submenu">
      <ul class="submenu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Факультеты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Кафедры</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Магистратура</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>




Спасибо вам большое за ответ. Но к сожалению при нажатии стрелочки назад появляется 3 блок сведений. Или просто нажать на мгик появиться блок и нажать назад появиться блок вообще который относиться к has-sub-submenuю Как можно решить эту проблему?

@Лев обновил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста, устраивает ли Вашим критериям.
